# How can I handle fake 1-n relationship in Laravel Backpack?

Tags: php, laravel, relationship, laravel-backpack

I have an old db under my application where not all relations are actually SQL relations, but some of them are stored in a string column.

Ex.

```
Tables: Tags, Articles
Table Articles has 'tags_ids' column where I have '33;44;82;' (the tag ids)
```

I would like to know if I can use the Laravel Backpack relationships UI with this kind of data.

I surely will have to "mutate" the data during the get and the set, but I can't find a way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think laravel supports something like that directly as a relationship.

You could certainly write a [custom column template](https://backpackforlaravel.com/docs/4.1/crud-columns#creating-a-custom-column-type) in backpack that would explode `$entry->tags_ids` on `;`, query Tags for those ids and then display them in a loop.

That said, IMHO, you'd be much better of adding an intermediate table like `article_has_tag` to map your tags and articles properly, then you could use all the built in features of laravel and backpack normally. If you still need the old application to work with the original data structure, you could write an "after insert/update" trigger for the `articles` and `article_has_tag` tables to keep them in sync (being careful to not cause an infinite loop of course).

Comment: thank you, the custom column is a good solution. About the intermediate table I'll think about it, as you could imagine there are hidden monsters of the past.

Comment: Personally I tackle that at the model level. Inside the model that has that column, I would use either an accessor or attribute casting to turn that string into a collection/array of connected entries. Then I'd use the `select_from_array` column and field for it.